# Adding large number of users in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I have 2000 odd people email ID which need to be added to SharePoint. Is that possible? If yes, suggest me an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Powershell to add bulk several users at a time

[Bulk User using Powershell](http://3sharp.com/blog/use-powershell-to-automate-groups-and-users-provisioning-in-sharepoint-online/)

or

you can use csv file.

Microsoft provides a template which you can download and add users into it.

[Adding Bulk User using CSV](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-several-users-at-the-same-time-to-Office-365-Admin-Help-1f5767ed-e717-4f24-969c-6ea9d412ca88)